# Can we keep job section into a seperate file and is it possible to include prometheus.yml

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

Can we keep the job section into a separate file and is it possible to include it in prometheus.yml.

We have multiple infrastructures to monitor,r so it would be helpful to aggregate with jobs and keep them in separate files.
Pls help

Comment: Nope, there is no such feature yet. The only way around this is by using some other tools. Perhaps if you have Ansible or Helm you can have the pieces in various files and them render them into one with templating.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep each job in a different file and use the "file_sd_configs" clause to "include" them in the Prometheus config file, like in the following example.

prometheus.yaml

```
  - job_name: blackbox
    metrics_path: /probe
    file_sd_configs:
      - files:
          - blackbox.yaml

  - job_name: node
    scheme: http
    metrics_path: /metrics
    file_sd_configs:
      - files:
          - node.yaml
```

blackbox.yaml

```
- labels:
    module: icmp
  targets:
    - SERVER1
    - SERVER2

- labels:
    module: https_2xx
  targets:
    - https://SYSTEM1
    - https://SYSTEM2
```

node.yaml

```
- labels:
    group: prod
  targets:
    - SERVER1:9100
    - SERVER2:9100

- labels:
    group: dev
  targets:
    - SERVER3:9100
    - SERVER4:9100
```

Besides the organization, another advantage is that it is not necessary to reload the Prometheus settings every time these files are changed (this is done automatically).

More info in the Prometheus documentation [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#file_sd_config).